# Implicit conversion - Linq-to-SQL and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have an issue where I am in VB.Net, Linq-to-SQL and performing a SQL update to a SQL Server table. My DBA tells me there is an implicit conversion from `smallint` to `int` going on when passing the key values to the table being updated, thus degrading performance.

The values being passed in are of type **Integer**, and the corresponding SQL Server key columns are of type **int**.

In the code sample below, `acctPlan.AccountNumber` and `acctPlan.FundPlanID` are both of **Integer** type (Int32) and the corresponding key columns `accountnumber` and `fundplanid` types being updated in the `ftpsInvAcctPlans` table are both of type **int**.

So they look the same to me; can't understand why there would be an implicit conversion from smallint to int, like he tells me is happening (in the code sample below, the values in `acctPlan` are from a Linq-to-SQL query result set, and the line of code is in the middle of a loop).

I was thinking of putting the values of `acctPlan.AccountNumber` and `acctPlan.FundPlanID` into local variables to match the `int` types in the SQL Server table, but I don't see where that would make a difference. They are already the same size.

Code in question (in the middle of a loop):

```vb
sqlString.AppendLine(String.Format("update ftpsInvAcctPlans Set balance={0} where accountnumber={1} And fundplanid={2};",
                                   rLine.Balance,
                                   acctPlan.AccountNumber,
                                   acctPlan.FundPlanID))
```

Any idea why there apparently is an implicit conversion from `smallint` to `int` in the code segment?

Comment: If you ignore, for a moment, the fact that you're not parameterizing your query, the SQL that's built here produces those values as *literals*. SQL Server parses those as part of the query and almost certainly treats them as 32-bit integers by default. If *any* conversion of those literals is going to be inefficient, it's SQL Server's fault, not yours, because you have no control over that. Using a `CAST` expression would only exacerbate the problem because the literal would still be there.

Comment: On the other hand, if you parameterize the query, you define the type and the value is passed as the exact type through the RDS protocol (any conversion happens in .NET code, in that case), so if there's a way to prevent inappropriate conversions, parameterization is it. Plus, it doesn't have to regenerate the execution plan, so there's that benefit, too. Either way, though, I call *nonsense*.

Comment: If you're using Linq to SQL, why are you using dynamic SQL to update?

Comment: Did it not occur to you to ask the DBA exactly where the conversion is occurring?

Comment: BTW, I meant TDS protocol above.